# Storage method while learning angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently learning angularjs and trying to build a listapp.

I'm struggling with deciding which method of storage I should be using while building the prototype.

Currently I'm using an object that I bind to the scope but it's not working very well for me.

- Listname

  - List type
  - List item

    - text
    - done

I want to be able to add, delete and edit from the storage.

Any suggestions, links, tutorials, guidance or whatever is appreciated!

Also I'm planning to move over to firebase later (I feel it just adds an extra layer of complexity atm while I'm learning angular).

Comment: Why cannot use browser localstorage?Theres an angular module for it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're just learning/prototyping, local storage should suit your needs.

`localStorage.setItem('key', 'value');`

`localStorage.getItem('key'); // returns 'value'`

Answer (score 3):

For learning/prototyping you can use [MongoLab database](https://mongolab.com/) as a storage (up to 500 MB it's free). As MongoLab database is hosted, you don't have to care about configuring your development environment (i.e. installing database server, database client, or anything else). You just create some simple database on the web page (via [GUI admin tool](http://blog.mongolab.com/2012/01/mongodb-gui-admin-tool-for-all/)) and then use an URL in angularjs code like:

```
var url = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/angularjs-intro/collections/users?apiKey=terrPcifZzn01_ImGsFOIZ96SwvSXgN9";
return $http.get(url);
```

See how it was used in this [AngularJS tutorial](http://blog.pluralsight.com/angularjs-step-by-step-services).